# Run nping through proxy server ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, tcp, proxy, ping

I am working on developing a Python program to ping websites through TCP. I used `nping` to ping websites through TCP continuously for a certain period of time, and it works great. After that, I added a proxy server option in the code to make `nping` work even through proxy server.

Next I installed a Squid proxy server and configured successfully. Now my problem is that `nping` works even with proxy server without any proxy authentication. I accessed the `nping` command in terminal, and it works, but other commands such as `sudo apt-get update` stop and show "proxy authentication required". Why is `nping` working even with proxy server enabled?

I read several articles and found that `ping` transfers ICMP packets, so it can't be blocked through proxy server. But `nping` send TCP packets, so why is it not getting blocked by the proxy server?

Comment: Which probe mode are you using for `nping`? Is it `--tcp-connect` or `--tcp` ?

Comment: It also depends on the proxy server configuration. The proxy server might be configured for http/https/ftp traffic but allowing other tcp traffic. Since apt-get runs over http(s), it is being blocked.

Comment: in both the ways, it works

Comment: Thanks for the answer....